# Confusion about finding information in a hash table when there is a collision

Tags: hashtable, collision, concept

I understand that if there is a collision in a hashtable you have a few options of storing the data. You could use some prime number to linearly traverse the array until you find a free spot. You could also rehash the entire table into a larger array. I'm sure there are other ways. What I don't understand is if there is a collision in the first place how would you know which row of data is the one you were looking for? Would I just not allow duplicate keys to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a big difference between a hash and a key (although they could sometimes be the same).

The key could be a very large number, a complex object consisting of many fields or anything really.
You apply your hash function to this key to get a hash.

So even if you disallow duplicate keys, you could still have duplicate hashes.

You often can't use your key as a hash directly because array indices are consecutive integers starting at 0, so it won't work if your key is too large, negative or not an integer, and you'll have to apply some sort of hash function.

---

If you want to store numbers between 1 and 10000, you would let the key be the number itself and could make the hash the remainder of the number divided by 1000 (and you'd thus have an array of size 1000 for the hash table).

Inserting 1001 will put it at index 1. If you try to insert 2001, it will also try to go to index 1 and you'll have a collision.

* The key could either be the entire value you want to store or only an identifier for it.

Comment: So I would disallow duplicate keys, use the key to hash to a spot in the table,store the unique key, if there was a collision I would resolve it and If I used the key to retrieve information I would check if the keys were the same to determine if I had the correct information when I found the spot on the table I had hashed to?

Comment: @CrinkleyCrewms Yes, that sounds about right. Note that if you're looking for an element, you'll need to do something similar to your collision resolution steps to find all possible elements corresponding to that hash - for  example, for [linear probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing), you'll need to start at the index corresponding to the hash and iterate through the array until you find an empty spot, because nothing after that spot can have the same hash (removing elements are non-trivial), and compare each key to the key you're looking for to see if it exists in the table.